# dirty reads: Different results within single query?

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server 2014, when I issue the following SQL:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED

SELECT * FROM TableA
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM TableB
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM TableA WHERE TableA.ID = TableB.ID
)
```

Is it possible to read different versions of one table even within a single Statement because of dirty reads?

**Example:** Reading 2 Rows from TableA in the first part of the union but reading just 1 Row from TableA in the inner select of the second part of the union because one row got deleted by another transaction meanwhile.

Comment: If you are concerned about inconsistent results why are you using the read uncommitted isolation level in the first place?

Comment: @Sean Because I don't wanna block a process that could be writing to these tables at the same time. Snapshots are not an option because I'm using clustered columnstore indexes where READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT and snapshot Isolation-level aren't supported in sql2014.

Comment: Well if accuracy is important then don't use read uncommitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: yes, depending on the execution plan generated. It doesn't matter that you're doing it in a single statement; no special privileges are associated with a statement boundary. `READ UNCOMMITTED` means no locking on data for any reason, and that's exactly what you'll get. This is also why using that generally is very much not recommended; it's terribly easy to get inconsistent/"impossible" results. Heck, even a single `SELECT` is not safe: you're not even guaranteed that rows will not be skipped or duplicated!

Comment: `even a single SELECT is not safe` is quite a scary statement in terms of stale results. In general I use `(nolock)` table hint in all my select statements. Is that not a good habit? So I can conclude that as long as I'm not applying a lock on entire table during select/read operation I may get dirty reads. Is it?

Comment: @RBT: The default mode is `READ COMMITTED`, which takes care of dirty reads just fine, without any need for such drastic measures as table locks. But yes, putting `NOLOCK` everywhere [is a bad habit](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/AaronBertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/).

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me its god damn possible.

The query execution plan will look like this:
[image: Execution plan example]

It looks like there will be two different reads from TableA, so it really depends on time delay between them and amount of CRUD operation made to those table.

READ UNCOMMITTED is really not so great choice for such query.